# Issues when converting a class component to functional component

Tags: reactjs

I've attempted to convert the following `demo.js` class component [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder/tree/master/sandbox_simple?file=/src/demo/demo.js) into a functional component over [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rqbfc123-zj39s6?file=/src/demo/demo.js) (demo.js) and when I attempt to make a change, I receive the error:

> immutableTree is not defined

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's check your lines 131 - 144 in detail:

```
const onChange = (immutableTree, config) => {
    immutableTree = immutableTree; // <-- why are you assigning the same var to itself?
    config = config;  // <-- why are you assigning the same var to itself?
    updateResult(); // <-- you are not passing any variables here

    const jsonTree = getTree(immutableTree);
    const { logic, data, errors } = jsonLogicFormat(immutableTree, config);
  };

  const updateResult = throttle(() => {
    setState({ tree: immutableTree, config: config }); // <-- but here you expect variables to be used
  }, 100);
```

The solution:
We need to ensure that our updateResult function is getting the variables it needs in order to proceed.

The corrected version:

```
 const onChange = (immutableTree, config) => {
    updateResult(immutableTree, config);

    const jsonTree = getTree(immutableTree);
    const { logic, data, errors } = jsonLogicFormat(immutableTree, config);
  };

  const updateResult = throttle((immutableTree, config) => {
    setState({ tree: immutableTree, config });
  }, 100);
```