# TypeError issue when converting a class component to a functional component

Tags: reactjs

Continuing on from a previous [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72225319/issues-when-converting-a-class-component-to-functional-component) involving the conversions from a class component to a functional component, I am now having issues with both the `reset` and `clear` button operations and unsure how to fix.

When clicking on both these buttons, I am getting the error:

> TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'settings')

My codebase can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rqbfc123-zj39s6?file=/src/demo/demo.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is you have replaced the whole state object with `tree` value. So you need to spread `state` and then set the `tree` value in it. like this `...state`, please check following code:

```
    const resetValue = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      tree: initTree
    });
  };

  const clearValue = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      tree: loadTree(emptyInitValue)
    });
  };
```

Comment: Really appreciate your assistance and your response. That solved my issue.